# VSTS GIT merge develop branch into master without master thinking it is 1 change-set ahead?

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS GIT source control repository and splitting my development into two branches, develop for on-going development, and then a master branch to release from.

Everything is going great except when I want to merge my develop branch into master, the pull-request completes, but it leaves the master branch '1 ahead' of the develop branch, and the VSTS GUI keeps prompting me to create a pull request from master back into develop. When I compare the branches there are of course no differences.

How can I merge my develop branch into master without GIT thinking master is now 1 ahead and making it look like everything is out of sync?

Thank you!

Comment: `keeps prompting me to create a pull request from master into main` - you mean from develop into master?

Comment: Yes sorry, edited. After merging from develop into master, VSTS Branch GUI keeps prompting claiming master is 1-change ahead of develop and prompting me to create another pull request from master back into develop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding VSTS git pull request merge, it generates the new commit for pull request merge with different ID at branch level of repository. You can check it in Code > Files > Select the repository > Select a branch > History.

For example:

[image]

[image]

So, for m1 branch, the pointer point to 25a5b862…, but for master branch, it points to cc36e063…, that why master has 1 head of m1.

However, if you merge the branch by using Git command and push to the server, then the commit ids are the same, so the ahead of value is 0.

Regarding your problem, since you merged develop branch to master, you can set master branch as the compare branch (click … > Set as compare branch). (result: 1 behind of master)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Regarding the solutions above, I can't merge the branch using Git command because I can´t push master into the server after that (master should be merged via Pull Request). And I don't want to set master as the compare branch. Is there any other solution that does not create the merge commit so that both branches are stay at the same point?

Comment: I'm at the same point as @DamiánPereira . I want master to always be at a point where it is stable so allowing devs to push straight to it is not an option. Unfortunately though, the only way to prevent this is to force PRs to the branch, which will always result in having one commit ahead of the develop branch. What I really want is to say "ok now this commit # that I just pushed to develop is now ready for a version release, let me sync it to master and have it launch the release pipeline". Seems like something that should be pretty straightforward to me... :s

Answer (score 1):

When you `merge develop` branch into `master` branch a new merge commit is created in master (commit message like `Merge branch 'develop' of <repo-name>` into master) but this new merge commit is not present in your `develop` branch.

so, when you check out to 'develop' branch git thinks `develop` are one commit (merge commit) behind from the `master`.

> master branch '1 ahead' of the develop branch

You can Pull `master` into `develop` to ignore this message.

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git pull origin master
```

Comment: So via a bash terminal on a local development PC this is fine, but via the VSTS GUI it doesn't really seem to give an option to sort this out? The only option is to PR back into develop from master, which then creates the same problem of master being 1-behind, etcetera.